# How to attach an object to a rotating circle in box2d cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to make an object get attached on a collision point to a circle that is rotating, but the player needs to get attached with a constant point on the player. For example the player is moving back and forth and when the user touches the screen and the player jumps up but what I need is that when the player collides with the circle it attaches it's legs to it and continues rotating with the circle. So I wanted to know how to make this kind of collision joint in cocos2d box2d?

Comment: I believe the flash version of box2d has a b2WeldJoint. Perhaps you could adapt a solution from that.

Answer (score 0):

When the collision between the user and the circle is detected, you could run an action that calls a callback function (perhaps a CCCallFuncND). The callback function could be passed pointers to both bodies (wrapped in NSValue valueWithPointer) and create an arbitrary joint between them. This would be done by first instantiating a b2JointDef of the desired type, defining bodyA and bodyB for that joint as the two bodies you'd like "stuck together", and then calling b2World->CreateJoint().

In terms of attaching the player body to a *specific point* on the circle body, you'd have to do so via some parameter of the joint def like anchorPoint. For example b2PrismaticJoints have anchorPoint which defines the center of the joint's range of motion.